# Prove that sigma algebra of random variables ordered negatively is a filtration

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, filtrations

I have a problem with a tricky exercise in stochastic process that take negativ integers for the time.

Let be $(U_{t})_{t \in T}$ sequence of iid random variables in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},p)$ with $T=\{-1,-2,...\}$ non negativ set of integers and let be $S_t := U_t+U_{t+1}+...+U_{-1}$.

If we define $\mathcal{H}_t$:= $\sigma(S_t,U_{t-1},U_{t-2},...)$, prove that $(\mathcal{H}_t)_{t \in T}$ is a filtration.

The definition of filtration is that for every time $t1 <= t2$, $\mathcal{F_{t_{1}}} \subset \mathcal{F_{t_{2}}}$ so I can't find a way to prove it because we work with negativ integers in time and it changes the inclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,
$$
S_{-1}=U_{-1}, S_{-2}=U_{-1}+U_{-2}=S_{-1}+U_{-2},\ldots,
$$
and in general, $S_{t}=S_{t+1}+U_{t}$.
Thus,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}_{-1}&=\sigma(U_{-1},U_{-2},U_{-3},\ldots),\\
\mathcal{H}_{-2}&=\sigma(S_{-2},U_{-3},U_{-4},\ldots)=\sigma(S_{-2})\vee\sigma(U_{-3},U_{-4}\ldots) \\
&\qquad\subset\sigma(U_{-1},U_{-2})\vee \sigma(U_{-3},U_{-4},\ldots) \\
&=\mathcal{H}_{-1}, \\
\cdots \\
\mathcal{H}_{t}&=\sigma(S_{t},U_{t-1},U_{t-2},\ldots)=\sigma(S_{t})\vee\sigma(U_{t-1},U_{t-2}\ldots) \\
&\qquad\subset\sigma(S_{t+1},U_{t})\vee \sigma(U_{t-1},U_{t-2},\ldots) \\
&=\mathcal{H}_{t+1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you  very much for your answer ! thats very clear but just one thing on your proof. Why $\sigma (S_{-2},U_{-3},U_{-4}...) = \sigma (S_{-2}) \lor \sigma(U_{-3},U_{-4}...)$ ?

Comment: @finquant75 Note that for random variables $X$and $Y$, one has $\sigma(X,Y)=\sigma(\sigma(X)\cup\sigma(Y))\equiv \sigma(X)\vee\sigma(Y)$. See, e.g., [Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469278/about-unions-of-sigma-algebra-being-sigma-algebras) and [Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2529417/sigma-algebra-genrated-by-two-random-variables).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the $\vee$ symbol. It is "maximum" or union ?

Comment: @finquant75 $\mathcal{F}_1\vee\mathcal{F}_2\equiv \sigma(\mathcal{F}_1\cup \mathcal{F}_2)$. See this [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#Combining_%CF%83-algebras).